# Почему не выводится первая строка из MySQL БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Код выводит все записи, кроме первой (проблема)
Запрос:

```
    $querycom = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE el=$el"; 
    $resultcom = mysql_query($querycom);
```

Вывод на страницу:

```
 while($r=mysql_fetch_array($resultcom)){
echo '<div align="center" id="addkomment">'.$r[comment].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: А если убрать условие WHERE el=$el, то выведет нормально?

Comment: Нет, выводит все записи, кроме первой.

Comment: Construct, да,в файле запроса к базе...убрал, ПОМОГЛО,спасибо

Comment: @glarionenko, только это не я вам помог)

Comment: Ой,ну в общем ВСЕМ спасибо)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вы случайно не выполнили `mysql_fetch_array()` перед циклом?

Comment: Точно, скорее всего так, раз первый не выводится только.

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное

Comment: Пожалуйста)

Answer (score -1):

```
$r['comment']
```

Пропущены кавычки. Строковые индексы массива должны быть в кавычках.

Comment: Это скорее всего описка, потому что препроцессор дал бы знать об этой ошибке и код бы просто не выполнился...